# System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to migrate some old code to .NET core. Basically, I want a controller action to determine the type of the model specified in the view.cshtml file. Here is the concept:

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/determine-models-from-views-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

My problem is that I can't find what should replace BuildManager in this line:

Type compiledViewType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(path);

It was in System.Web.Compilation. Is it gone, or how do I access it now?

Thanks & regards,

-John

Comment: everything under `System.Web` has been replaced or is completely gone.

Comment: are you trying to do the exact same sitecore thing?

Comment: Basically the same thing, but not with Sitecore, with a different CMS (headless SaaS), where my code is running in a controller action. There must be some way to determine the type of the view model because the IDE validates it. Something must be compiling the views; how can I find that thing...